# c++ how to create an empty char array of the size of an existing char array?

Tags: c++

I want to create aValue with the size of pLine, because i don't want aValue to cut off the line if its longer than 128.

```
char aValue[128];
sscanf(pLine, "Word %127s", aValue);
```

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `std::string` and be done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you want a buffer with the length of the max of pLine

```
char *aValue=new char[strlen(pLine)];
sscanf(pLine, "Word %s", aValue);
```

do not forget to delete aValue after use:

```
delete[] aValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::string`, something like:

```
std::string aValue;
aValue.resize(strlen(pLine));
```

then you can get at the c-string with:

```
aValue.c_str();
```